# Can Apache HTTP server run on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, 64-bit

Our server OS is windows 2008 server enterprise edition, 64-bit and we want to use [Apache HTTP server](http://httpd.apache.org/).

I cannot find any introduction about whether it can or not run on 64-bit machine. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it can. Both a 32-bit and 64-bit build will work on a 64-bit machine/OS (with suitable libraries of course).

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Software Foundation has not released any official 64 bit binaries for Windows. However, it's open source so there is a third party unofficial 64 bit binary package for Windows. Same thing goes for PHP on Windows:

http://www.elxis.org/guides/developers-guides/64bit-apache-php-mysql-windows.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html

I'd personally go with the official binaries. It depends on what you are doing but performance increases can be negligible: http://www.scribd.com/doc/363677/Benchmarks-AMD64-in-32bit-mode-vs-64bit-mode-Ubuntu (on Linux anyways). Also looking quickly via Google there are some reports of problems with the unofficial 64 bit binaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the 64 bit binaries from apache lounge. You will require the proper Visual C++ libraries. Currently the latest version can be found under
http://www.apachelounge.com/download/ using VC14. The required Visual C++ redistributables will be those of VS 2013